# Count rows based on field values as column is SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of programs:

| ID | Program | AssignedPerson | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sample Program A | Person A | Done |
| 2 | Sample Program A | Person B | Cancelled |
| 3 | Sample Program A | Person C | Not Started |
| 4 | Sample Program B | Person A | Done |
| 5 | Sample Program B | Person C | Not Started |
| 6 | Sample Program C | Person B | Done |

I want to summarize the table to **generate Count per Status per Unique Program**

| Program | Done | Cancelled | NotStarted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample Program A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Sample Program B | 1 |  | 1 |
| Sample Program C | 1 |  |  |

**What's the most efficient way of doing this?** I fear that a sub-query will be slow, and I'm wondering if there's a better way. Is there?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: *"What's the most efficient way of doing this?"* Conditional Aggregation/Pivoting.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: [Try to Solve The Problem First](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) 
-- 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
-- 
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
--
[I Downvoted Because](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)
--
[Don't upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: It's always a good question to ask, the first time you run across this scenario. Expanding on Thom A's response, both `PIVOT` and "*Conditional Aggregation*" are the typical solutions. `PIVOT` is a built-in SQL syntax feature. Conditional aggregation is a technique that uses `COUNT()` or other aggregate functions together with a `CASE ..` expression to yield similar results. Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MqmoQy9o) that demonstrates both. Both will execute efficiently. Some developers find the conditional aggregation approach more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   Program
        ,count(case Status when 'Done' then 1 end)        as Done
        ,count(case Status when 'Cancelled' then 1 end)   as Cancelled
        ,count(case Status when 'Not Started' then 1 end) as Not_Started
from     t
group by Program
```

| Program | Done | Cancelled | Not_Started |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample Program A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Sample Program B | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Sample Program C | 1 | 0 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6ktixoAk)

Answer (score -2):

```
mysql> select Program,count(*)as AllSingleCount from (whatever you named your table) group by Status;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?